# Unable to upload to PyPI: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, server, setuptools, pypi

I am trying to upload a package to PyPI, but even after repeated tries I am getting the followin error:

```
HTTPError: 500 Internal Server Error from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Internal Server Error
```

The way I do it is this:`python3 -m twine upload dist/*` after running `python3 -m setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: PyPI had problems 2 days ago: https://status.python.org/incidents/y9l38rf0wq1h

Comment: @phd : Yeah I tried pinging upload.pypi.org and that fails although I can ping pypi.org. Interestingly, the link you posted says that the issue is resolved.

Comment: May be they have another issue. Anyway the question must be directed to PyPI support. We hardly can make anything here.

Comment: @phd : Absolutely. I just thought initially that I am doing something wrong while uploading.